# PowerShell to get AD Object containing more than 3 not necessarily consecutive digits

Tags: regex, powershell

I am working on a regex pattern for the below PowerShell code, so it can show any AD objects which has more than three digits as the name.

Ideally to match like:

```
Test-DL1-1-25932404
Firstname LastName-1810023568
SERVER-1-2102285680
```

Script:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter * |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\d\d\d\d' } |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The script above returns all AD objects with numbers.

Comment: What do you expect? `\d\d\d\d` just matches 4 consecutive digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ADObject -Filter * |
    Where-Object { ($_.Name -replace '\D').Length -gt 3 } |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

This will get rid of all non-digits and count how many remain, and will get 1-2-3-4-5 as well.

Comment: Here, `\d{4,}` will work the same as `\d{4}` since this is used to filter, not to extract.

Comment: Cool, thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I learn some new stuff as well.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer So what was the problem? What worked for you?

Comment: The filtering Where-Object { ($_.Name -replace '\D').Length -gt 3 }, this is so cool :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "*Here, \d{4,} will work the same as \d{4}*" - good point. Edited it out after subsequent comments.